# Share program variable values with Javascript running on browser

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm developing a C# windows form application which scan passports in a client PC
in the same client PC user is going to open a webpage with which has some textboxes.

Is there any way to share some values of windows form application with the browser page?

(IS there anyway to invoke some functions in Windows App through RPC from the browser JavaScript, or any mechanism of share or send these values)
[image].

Comment: You could use querystring to send your values, if it's your web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the web server as a mutually accessible resource. The c# application can send data to the server, and the web browser can poll/listen for updates from the web server using AJAX. If the Windows  application is also connected to the server, it could receive updates from the web page.

Alternatively, if you want to do a one-time sharing of data between the Windows app and the website, you could:

- collect data in Windows app
- send it to server
- receive a unique ID
- launch a web browser with the unique ID in the query string
- website finds the data which was just sent by the Windows app.

Certainly there are other ways to do it as well. My goal would be to avoid having to have any knowledge of the web browser in use, e.g. requiring a plugin to be downloaded to facilitate the communication between the browser and the Windows application.

Comment: +1. also some sort of session Id probably needed to be send to browser's page anyway (query string as Michal Klouda suggested is an option).

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to implement a small `http` server in your C# app that can respond to http requests.  Your web page can then make a `GET` request to the appropriate URL to fetch the data to populate the fields.

Comment: +1 reasonable approach if multiple browsers need to be supported and there is large amount of data. Make sure to use some non-standard port (to avoid collisions with 80/443) and read on cross-site scripting/"same origin policy" to know how to get data between domains (page's and localhost).